# Extract Parameter from URL Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

does anybody has an excel formula for me which just gives me back the clickid parameter? Unfortunately this parameter is not always at the same position so I can't fix it with character count. It should always be between &clickid= and &

```
https://app.appsflyer.com/id770725904?pid=website_adwords&c=C_DEU_billig&tl_rf=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&tl_nw=g&tl_mt=e&clickid=EAIaIQobChMIj5zchvqs4AIVQamaCh06NQlOEAAYASACEgJhRPD_BwE&af_keywords=billig+telefonieren+nach+iran&af_c_id=1597316081&af_adset_id=60710335432&af_ad_type=1t1&af_adset=Iran&af_ad_id=303032652682
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for sure a regular expression will be able to find this, but a rather simple formula could do the trick aswell. For example:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("clickid=",A1)+8,FIND("&",A1,FIND("clickid=",A1)+8)-(FIND("clickid=",A1)+8))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will work but someone may have a tidier option ...

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("clickid",A1),1000),"clickid=", ""),FIND("&",SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("clickid",A1),1000),"clickid=", ""))-1)
```

Throw your URL into cell A1 and test it out.